# MySQL - Select specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to print specific date in MySql. However, when I use the following query:

```
select 2000-01-01;
```

I also tried:

```
select CAST(2000-01-01 AS date);
```

but it always print NULL. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You need single quotes around the date constant.

Comment: Select 2001-01-01 would print 1999.

Comment: Minus is an arithmetic operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can use by this way (select "2000-01-01");

that is the result (2000-01-01)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your column type is date and not datetime type.Try this and see,

```
 select CAST(2000-01-01 AS DATETIME);
```